# ggplot geombar or geomhistogram in Python. Graph has gaps in each bar

Tags: python, ggplot2, geom-bar, python-ggplot

[image: Geombar from ggplot in python.]

Here is the code for this geombar

```
gg1 = ggplot(aes(y='y', x='x'), data=new_data) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +   
    labs(x="Hour of day",y="Hourly entries") +
    ggtitle("Riders per a hour of day for weekdays")
```

new_data is two columns I took out of a larger database. The data is large. The x variable our hours in 4 hour blocks so (0,4,8,12 etc..) and the y variable are the amount of entries within those blocks.

If I then do this.

```
gg1 = ggplot(aes(y='y', x='x', fill = 'r'), data=new_data) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    labs(x="Hour of day",y="Hourly entries") +
    ggtitle("Riders per a hour of day for weekdays")
```

I usually get

```
ValueError: incompatible sizes: argument 'bottom' must be length 22570 or scalar
```

Now I just get the same graph as above.

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example using A) one of the data sets that comes with ```ggplot2``` or B) a subset of your own data?

Comment: It looks like you might just need to make x a factor. Make sure your data is "long" rather than "wide". See ```reshape2```'s ```melt``` function to do this.

Comment: @Nancy this question is on ggplot on python (I had to do a double take myself too...) Not sure what the `reshape2` equivalent fo rpython is.

Comment: @Heroka Ha, I didn't see that either. Well we still need a bit more information to try it in Python; I'm sure some people would actually be glad to see a python ggplot question.